# Overlay Marker Points with ids on google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapping

I have what I think is a tricky question, but hopefully someone on here can keep me from tearing my hair out!

I'm currently trying to figure out how to overlay a bunch of markers on a google map overlaid with a hosted tileJson layer.

I'm also trying to follow this tutorial so that I can load pictures and text into the sidebar when the user clicks on any of the map points:

http://www.dougv.com/2007/07/12/using-ajax-to-update-a-non-map-div-via-google-maps-apis-gdownload-and-gmarker-onclick-event/

The tutorial is designed for maps api2 (I'm using 3) although it looks like it could easily be updated for api 3.

Right now, in part because of the javascript connector that simplifies importing the custom tiles, I can't seem to get markers to work, let alone connect them to databases, and access them from outside the map window.

https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/axler/Web%20Deep%20Map/Web%20Map%20Google%20Maps/index2.html
Live map tiles... at the above link.  No points are working yet but I put some sample points in a list in the code.

Any suggestions?  Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GOOGLE MAPS TILEMILL</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD6VG2UbuMLDCQoZ-GOPZl_PU7r1jXzejU&sensor=false">
        </script>
      <script
        src='wax/dist/wax.g.min.js'
        type='text/javascript'></script>
      <link href='wax/theme/controls.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='style.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type ='text/css' />
        <link href='controls.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' /><script>
    var map;
    var sidebar;


    function pageLoad() {
    sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    addPoint(1, 'Howards Fish House', 46.72.30616121527788, -92.15);
    addPoint(2, 'Rices Point', 46.78, -92.18);
    addPoint(3, 'Wild Rice Seeding Area', 46.80, -92.22);
        wax.tilejson('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/slre.st-louis-river-estuary.jsonp',
      function(tilejson) {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('mymap'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.72, -92.15),
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        zoom: 12,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });

      // Use this code to set a new layer as a baselayer -
      // which means that it'll be on the bottom of any other
      // layers and you won't see Google tiles
      map.mapTypes.set('mb', new wax.g.connector(tilejson));
      map.setMapTypeId('mb');

    //I want to place a number of points on top of the MapBox hosted tile layer that is specified by wax.tilejson



    });


    }
function addPoint(pid, name, lat, lng) {
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point);
                map.setMap(marker);

                var info = '<strong>' + name + '</strong><br />';
                info += 'For more information, click the icon.';

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                    marker.openInfoWindow(info);
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                    map.closeInfoWindow();
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    details.innerHTML = '<em>Loading information ...</em>';
                    showDivInfo(pid);
                });
            }

    </script>

    </head>


    <body onload="pageLoad()" onunload="pageUnload()">
    <div id='sidebar'>
        <h2>Explore the St. Louis River Estuary</h2>
        <p>Click on the map points to learn about the stories and science that define the region!</p>
        <p><span class='source'>Source: <a href='http://www.stlre.pebbleonline.com'>Main Web Page</a></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id='mymap'></div>


    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: please provide a link to your map hosted online. We cant run a debugger on a block of posted code.

Comment: Keep in mind the current code lacks a lot of the functionality contained in the question...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where is the your current best attempt at adding the markers?

Comment: ok - i just updated my code to include my ill-fated attempt.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  map.setMap(marker); looks wrong.

should be

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

:)

Comment: Good catch on that! Points still won't load though. Is there a specific place in the hierarchy that I need to put the addPoint functions?

Comment: Ah, well they need to be after the "var map = new google.maps.Map" that creates the map itself. can only add the points to the map - after the map has been created!

Comment: And in fact you dont want the 'var' in there either. Want to assign the map object to the global map variable, not a new local one.

Comment: still no dice. thanks for sticking with this...any other ideas of what  might be wrong? When I tried creating a simple marker before, it seemed to work fine, so there must be something wrong with the way I've ordered things in the code or the add points function itself. The example tutorial that I linked to in the question uses google maps api 2, and the author has a working example that uses api v2.

Comment: Give us a link to your page - where you actully trying this. At the moment, its hard to help you, because we debugging 'though' you. If we can run our debuggers on the code - we can see more.

Comment: For that matter are you running this though a debugger - using the Developer tools in Chrome or Firefox (for example)? The console may already be giving you useful error messages

Comment: I'm not a programmer by training so I'm pretty new at this...I'll try running the debugger.

Comment: Its very useful to learn about it, see also https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/debuggingmaps

Comment: i didn't find any errors that were specific to my marker additions. seems like it should be a simple solution!

Comment: still need to move the addPoint functions to be after the map is created.

Comment: where exactly would you suggest putting it? i've tried a number of places but it still won't work